# Question about path products and constant paths

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory

> Let $i_p$ be the constant map at $p$ being the origin of the path $f$.  Prove that: $f * f^{-1} \simeq i_p \text{ rel } \dot I$.

The proof says to subdivide $I \times I$ and let the homotopy be:

$$H(s,t) = 
\begin{cases}
f(2s(1-t)),  & \text{if $0 \le s \le \frac{1}{2}$} \\
f(2(1-s)(1-t)), & \text{if $\frac{1}{2} \le s \le 1$}
\end{cases}$$

How did they come upon the two functions inside the $f$'s?  And how is $I \times I$ being subdivided here?  I know the inside functions are functions of the form: $$\theta_t(s) = s \frac{b_1-b_2}{s_1-s_2} + \frac{s_2b_2 - s_2b_1}{s_1-s_2}$$ where $\theta_t : [s_1, s_2] \rightarrow [b_1, b_2]$ is an affine map that maps $s_i$ to $b_i$, but I'm not sure of what the subdivision is for this.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, you know that $f^{-1}(s) := f(1-s)$, by definition.
Then, the product path $f \star f^{-1}$ is equal to
$$
f \star f^{-1} =
\begin{cases}
  f(2s) & s \in [0,\frac12] \\
  f^{-1}(2s-1) = f(2(1-s)) & s \in [\frac12,1],
\end{cases}
$$
again by definition of *product path*. Note that the endpoints are the same and they equal $p$.

Finally, you need a homotopy (relative to $\dot{I}$). Your additional information is that $i_p(s) = p = f(0)$ over $[0,1]$.

To me, the most simple homotopy to think about, in this case, is

$$
H(s,t) =
\begin{cases}
  f(2s\cdot t) & s \in [0,\frac12] \\
  f^{-1}((2s-1)\cdot t) = f(1 - t(2s-1)) & s \in [\frac12,1],
\end{cases}
$$

which is continuous and satisfies the conditions to be eligible as a homotopy.
The homotopy you provided just goes *the opposite way*: the one I provided satisfies $H(s,0) = i_p$ and $H(s,1) = f \star f^{-1}$.

Note that you can find more than a homotopy, given two functions.